# How to display correct page number in body of ssrs(In every page of the output)

Tags: reporting-services, reporting, ssrs-2012

i Placed this code in my report property code

```
Public Function PageNumber() as String
     Dim str as String
     str = Me.Report.Globals!PageNumber.ToString()
     Return str
End Function
```

and called in my text box in body of report  Like this

```
 =Code.PageNumber()
```

It was not able to repeat textbox on each page. 
It is showing the **page number as 1** only on first page.

need to show **pagenumber** in each page of the output in body of the report

Kindly help me on this if u have any solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Follow the steps 1 below to do pagination:
1)
1.1. Click the Details group in the Row Groups pane.
1.2. From the Tablix member Properties pane, expand “Group”-> “PageBreak”.
1.3. Set the “BreakLocation” to “End” and set the “Disable” property to the expression like below:
    =IIF(rownumber(nothing) mod 40=0,false,true)
The above point 1 is use to do pagination in Report output(Display only 40 records per page in output)

2) **use custom code:**

```
Public Function PageNumberno(val as integer) as String
     Dim str as String
     str =(val/40)
     Return str
End Function
```

3) Create Calculated column in Dataset and enter =0 in expression

4) In 2 Calculated Column
    1)Pageno
    2)No in Dataset

In Report Body use Expression for **PageNo** :

```
  =code.PageNumberno(Rownumber("DataSet1"))
```

use Expression for **No** :

```
 =IIF(Instr(code.PageNumberno(Rownumber("DataSet1"))
,".")<>0,
(Left(code.PageNumberno(Rownumber("DataSet1")),
(Instr(code.PageNumberno(Rownumber("DataSet1")),".")-1))+1)
,code.PageNumberno(Rownumber("DataSet1"))
)
```

5)Right click and insert column on Right Side and in Column name add code in Text box

```
=ReportItems!No.Value
```

**Note:** No is calculated Field column name.

6)Under AdvancedMode
IN Row Group select **Static** and Set **RepeatOnNewPage**  Properties to **True**

**In the Above Column created under point 5 will display correct page no in every page in body of the report**

I have Tried and its working Fine..Try it.

Answer (score 0):

I usually put a text box in the footer of the report (which will automatically display on every page) with the following line of code in it (no report property code needed):

```
="Page " & CStr(Globals!PageNumber) & " of " & CStr(Globals!TotalPages)
```

Comment: I need to display page number in Report body..not in header or footer

Comment: The same formula will probably work - just not sure how you'll get it to show on every page unless you have a grouped table or something...not sure how your report is set up, so I can't help you much more.

Comment: Could you add the report page as a `Textbox!ItemXXX.value` and then reference the textbox throughout your report?